# Python: store off list value or access list multiple times

Tags: python, performance, list

If a value in a python list will be used multiple times, is it more efficient to store it as a variable instead of accessing the array?

For example, if there are a large number of arbitrary functions all performed on the value at the same index of a list, like below:

```
for i in range(len(aList)):
    funcA(aList[i])
    funcB(aList[i])
    # etc...
    funcN(aList[i])
```

vs

```
for i in range(len(aList)):
    val = aList[i]
    funcA(val)
    funcB(val)
    # etc...
    funcN(val)
```

1. Is there appreciable overhead associated with getting the value in the list each time? The [documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) shows that the time complexity to get an item from a list is O(1), but it doesn't say what the constant is. Would it be noticeable if a large number of functions use the value?
2. Will the compiler be able to optimize this? I'm thinking it might, because it can tell if any of the functions that are called will modify the value at that index, and either save the value or a reference to the array at the index, depending on whether it could change.
3. In case there isn't a significant time loss associated with looking up the value each time, I would tend to save the value into a local variable for readability's sake. Is there a "pythonic" suggestion for this?

Comment: I miniscule overhead. Neither the compiler nor the interpreter can optimize it - how would it know if any of the functions you call will modify the value?. Python is way too dynamic of a language for that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is technically more efficient to fetch it once, although it is unlikely to be noticeable compared to the time it takes to execute the functions. However, there is no need to use indexing at all; just iterate over the values themselves instead of the list indices.

```
for val in aList:
    funcA(val)
    funcB(val)
    ...
    funcC(val)
```